# Restlet: use "index.html" as default for serving static content using CLAP protocol

Tags: restlet

I want to put static content in my restlet based web service. The static part must reside into the jar of the service. The code I'm using is:

`Directory directory = new Directory(getContext(), "clap://class/pageData");
router.attach("/page", directory);`

If I access the service with `.../page/index.html` the page is displayed in the browser. But the call of `.../page` or `.../page/` results in a "Not found" error page.

How can I make index.html the default file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to specify implicitely the `indexName` property on your directory:

```
Directory directory = new Directory(
     getContext(), "clap://class/pageData");
directory.setIndexName("index.html");
router.attach("/page", directory);
```

It seems that the default value is `index` and not `index.html`...

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: Thank you, /page/ works now only /page doesn't. Is there a way to get this working?

Comment: This works for me with version 2.3.5. Which version do you use?

Comment: I use 2.3.5 too. Using Chrome it fails but Firefox works.